# Override inline style with a CSS mixin in Polymer 2

Tags: css, polymer, polymer-2.x

Is there a way to override the **inline style** of a component in Polymer 2 with a **CSS mixin**?

In Polymer 1, I had a similar code as below in my component to do that and it is working fine (see #1 image):

```
<style>
    paper-menu-button {
        display: block;

        --paper-menu-button-dropdown: {
            position: relative !important;
            top: auto !important;
            left: auto !important;
            display: block;
        };

        --paper-menu-button-content: {
            max-width: none !important;
            max-height: none !important;
            display: block;
        };
    }
</style>
```

But with Polymer 2, it is not working anymore (see #2 image).

[JS bin](https://jsbin.com/yuwisar/3/edit?html,output)   for Polymer 2.

**1. Polymer 1 :**
CSS:

[image: Polymer 1 - CSS results]

Output:

[image: Polymer 1 - Output]

---

**2. Polymer 2:**
CSS:

[image: Polymer 2 - CSS results]

Output:
[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Here a [JS Bin](https://jsbin.com/yuwisar/3/edit?html,output) with a Polymer 2 paper-menu-button that have this problem.

Comment: Here some HTML results as I was not allowed to post more than two links:

  3. [Polymer 1 - HTML results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gNR8K.jpg)
  4. [Polymer 2 - HTML results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BZKvu.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `width:100%;` in `--paper-menu-button-dropdown`.

Working [JS Bin](https://jsbin.com/rirogiw/1/edit?html,output).

Also, notice that I have changed `iron-icon.html` to `iron-icons.html` for the arrow icon.